# $(e_{n})$ orthonormal basis, $(f_{n})$ orthonormal sequence such that $\sum\left\|e_{n}-f_{n}\right\|^{2}<\infty$ Then $(f_{n})$ is orthonormal basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a hilbert space, $(e_{n})$ a orthonormal basis of $H$, and, $(f_{n})$  a orthonormal sequence on $H$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\|e_{n}-f_{n}\right\|^{2}<\infty. \tag{I}$$
Show that $(f_{n})$ is also a orthonormal basis.

**Remark:** My idea was the following:

First I show the following fact:

> **Fact 1:**  Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a orthonormal basis of $H$, and let $(y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $H$ such that 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\|x_{n}-y_{n}\right\|^{2}<1. \tag{II}$$
>   Then, if $z\bot y_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $z=0$.

Let $f\bot f_{n}$ for all $n\leq 1$, then by (I) there exists $m$ such that
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\left\|e_{n}-f_{n}\right\|^{2}<1. \tag{III}$$
Therefore, by **Fact 1** we have that $\left\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{m},f_{m+1},f_{m+2},\ldots\right\}$ is total in $H$.

**I need to show that $\left\{f,f_{1},\ldots,f_{m}\right\}$ is linearly dependent.**

Comment: In your fact 1, don't you mean $z \perp y_n$ instead of $z \perp x_n$? Otherwise it's pretty trivial.

Comment: @Demophilus It was a typo, it's already corrected.

Comment: Also, with that edit, you fact is wrong. If you let $(e_n)_n$ be any orthonormal basis and $y_1=0$ and $y_n=(1-e^{-n})e_n$ for $n \geq 2$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|y_n - x_n \|^2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{-2n} = e^{-4} \cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-2}}<1$ then $e_1 \perp y_n$ but clearly $e_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Demophilus I assume that you are assuming $(x_{n})_{n}=(e_{n})_{n}$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|y_n - x_n \|^2 =\|e_n \|^2+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{-2n} =1+ e^{-4} \cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-2}}=1+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{-2n} = 1+e^{-4} \cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-2}} \geq 1$$

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I forgot to add the first term in the series. I'll try to prove it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\span{\operatorname{span}}$

This solution uses ideas from  [Demophilus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/378264/demophilus) and  [DisintegratingByParts](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112478/disintegratingbyparts) , who removed his/her nearly complete solution for some unknown reason.

Take $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \|e_n-f_n\|^2  = c <1$ and take $V = \overline{\text{span}\{e_{m+1},e_{m+2}, \ldots\}}$.     Let $W = \span\{e_1, \dots, e_m\} = V^\perp$.  Let  $V' =  
\overline{\text{span}\{f_{m+1},f_{m+2}, \ldots\}}$.

There is an isometry $A'$ from $V$ to $V'$ determined by $e_j  \mapsto f_j$  for $j \ge m+1$.   Define $A : H = W \oplus V \to H$ by $A( w + v) = w + A'(v)$.   The range of $A$ is $W + V'$. 
Then
$$
(A - I)(w + v) = A'(v) - v = \sum_{ j = m+1}^\infty   \langle v, e_j\rangle  (f_j - e_j).
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
|| (A - I) (w + v)||   &\le   \sum_{ j = m+1}^\infty  | \langle v, e_j\rangle| \ \  ||  f_j - e_j||  \\
& \le   \left( \sum_{ j = m+1}^\infty  | \langle v, e_j\rangle|^2\right ) ^{1/2}
 \left( \sum_{ j = m+1}^\infty ||  f_j - e_j  ||^2\right )^{1/2}  \\
 & = c^{1/2}  ||v|| \le  c^{1/2}  ||w + v||, 
\end{aligned}
$$
where the very last estimate uses that $w$ and $v$ are orthogonal, so $||v + w||^2 = ||v||^2 + ||w||^2$.
Thus  $|| A - I ||\le c^{1/2} < 1$,     and $A$ is invertible. (See the proof sketch below.)   In particular $A$ is surjective so $W+ V' = H$.  Check that $W \cap V' = (0)$, so $H = W \oplus V'$  (not an orthogonal direct sum).

In particular $H/V'$ is $m$--dimensional, so $(V')^\perp$ is $m$ dimensional.  But $\{f_1,\ldots, f_m\}$ is an orthonormal subset of $(V')^\perp$ of cardinality $m$,  so $\{f_1,\ldots, f_m\}$  is an orthonormal basis of $(V')^\perp$.   Therefore $\{f_j : 1 \le j < \infty\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$.

Note:  In any Banach algebra with identity $I$ (and $||I|| = 1$)  if $x$ is an element satisfying $||x|| < 1$, then $I - x$ is invertible with inverse $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty x^j$.  Apply this in our context, noting $A = I - (I - A)$.

Comment: Very nice proof. I would maybe also mention why $\|A-I\|<1$ implies that $A$ is invertible. It's not hard to prove, but I imagine this wouldn't be obvious to someone seeing that for the first time.

Comment: A small detail that in general is not true is $\|v\|\leq \|w+v\|$.

Comment: Edited the solution to address the concerns of Diego Fonseca and Demophilus.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Take $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \|e_n-f_n\|^2 <1$ and take $V = \overline{\text{span}\{e_{m+1},e_{m+2}, \ldots\}}$. By your fact 1 we have that $V = \overline{\text{span}\{f_m,f_{m+1}, \ldots\}}$. Notice that $V^\perp = \text{span}\{e_1,\ldots, e_m\}$. But we also have that $\{f_1,\ldots, f_m\} \subset V^\perp$ is a linearly independent subset. Because $\dim V^\perp =m$, $\{f_1,\ldots, f_m\}$ is a basis of $V^\perp$. Then we must have that $(f_n)_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V \oplus V^\perp =H$ which concludes our proof.

Comment: This is not correct, as you don't know the closed span of the $f_j$ for $j > m$ is contained in $V$, so you cannot apply  Fact 1.

Comment: @fredgoodman Of course, thank you.