# Prove that if $\sum\|e_n-f_n\|^2<\infty$, then $\{f_n\}$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\{e_n\}$ and $\{f_n\}$ be orthonormal sequences in a Hilbert
>   space $H$ with $\|e_n\|=\|f_n\|=1$ and
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|e_n-f_n\|^2<\infty.$$
>   **Prove or disprove**: If $\{e_n\}$ is complete, then $\{f_n\}$ is also complete.

Actually if the condition is changed into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|e_n-f_n\|^2<1$, then the conclusion holds:

If $\{f_n\}$ is not complete, then there exists a nonzero $x \in \{f_n\}^{\perp}$. Since $\{e_n\}$ is complete, then
$$\|x\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(x,e_n)|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(x,e_n-f_n)|^2 \leq \|x\|^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|e_n-f_n\|^2,$$
which leads to a contradiction.

But now the method doesn't work so I am stuck. Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520730/e-n-orthonormal-basis-f-n-orthonormal-sequence-such-that-sum-left

Comment: @ThomasShelby: It helps a lot. Thank you so much.